# bash: /home/rathin/.profile:: No such file or directory while trying to reload it via "source ~/.profile" after editing it through "vi ~/.profile"

Tags: bash, .profile

After I edited my `~/.profile` via `vi` command, couldn't get out of it successfully.

So I closed the terminal and when I tried it again after reopening terminal, it showed duplicate file named `~/.profile.swp`. So I deleted it.

Now it shows

```
bash: /home/rathin/.profile:: No such file or directory
```

when I try

```
source ~/.profile
```

It also shows error

```
Error loading /home/user/.profile no such file or directory found.
```

when I restart my laptop.

This is the output of `vi ~/.profile`

```
~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

"~/.profile" 25 lines, 677 characters
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the first line in that file. It reads

```
~/.profile: ...
```

and bash tries to execute this file, the name of which ends with a `:`. That file does not exist, so bash complains, note the double`:` in the error messsge.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** The first line should be a comment

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
```

---

Therefore run

```
perl -i.bak -0777 -pe 's/^/# /' ~/.profile
```

The command adds a `#` at the beginning of the first line and creates a backup file: `~/.profile.bak`

---

*Explanation*

- `-0777` changes the line separator to undef, letting us to slurp the file, feeding all the lines to Perl in one go.
- `-p` processes the file line by line and prints the output.
- `-e` is what allows us to specify the Perl code we want to run right on the command line.

Comment: Simple copy and paste line, I love it!  +1  Tested it on my own, works great!  I updated my answer to reflect as well.  Thank you! =)